# Understanding writeValues of raster by parallel processing. Is it possible to writevalues for each raster while using mclapply fork cluster. R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster, r-raster, mclapply

I try to understand how to parallelize raster processing in R. My Goal ist to parallize the following on multiple cores with multiple rasters.
I process my raster blockwise and i try to parallelize it with mclapply or other functions. First i want to get the values of one raster or a rasterstack. and then i want to write the values to the object. When i am using multiple cores, it does not work, because different sub Processes want to write on the same time. Somebody know a solution for that?

So here is the process:

**get and create data**

```
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
s <- raster(r)
tr <- blockSize(r)
```

**then getValues and writevalues with a for loop**

```
s <- writeStart(s[[1]], filename='test.grd',  overwrite=TRUE)
for (i in 1:tr$n) {
  v <- getValuesBlock(r, row=tr$row[i], nrows=tr$nrows[i])
  s <- writeValues(s, v, tr$row[i])
}
s <- writeStop(s)
```

this works fine

**now trying the same on lapply**

```
s <- writeStart(s[[1]], filename='test.grd',  overwrite=TRUE)
#working with lapply
lapply(1:tr$n, function(x){
  v <- getValues(r, tr$row[x], tr$nrows[x])
  s <- writeValues(s,v,tr$row[x])
})
s <- writeStop(s)
```

works fine

**Now trying with mclapply with one core**

```
s <- writeStart(s[[1]], filename='test.grd',  overwrite=TRUE)

#does work with mclapply one core
parallel::mclapply(1:tr$n, function(x){
  v <- getValues(r, tr$row[x], tr$nrows[x])
  s <- writeValues(s,v,tr$row[x])
}, mc.cores = 1)
s <- writeStop(s)
```

also works

**now trying with mclapply on multiple cores**

```
s <- writeStart(s[[1]], filename='test.grd',  overwrite=TRUE)
#does not work with multiple core
parallel::mclapply(1:tr$n, function(x){
  v <- getValues(r, tr$row[x], tr$nrows[x])
  s <- writeValues(s,v,tr$row[x])
}, mc.cores = 2)
s <- writeStop(s)
```

So that does not work. I understand the logic, why it does not work.
My question now is: Suppose I have a rasterstack with 2 rasters. Could I use mclapply or another function from the parallel package to write this process differently. So I get the values of the block for both grids at the same time, but these values are only written to one rater per core.

For the solution I am looking for it is not acceptable to first get all values, safe them in an object and then write the values blockwise, because my rasters are to large.

I would be very happy if someone has a solution or just an idea or suggestion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the object returned by `raster::writeStart()` can only be processed in the same R process as it was created.  That is, it is *not* possible for a parallel R process to work with it.

The fact that the object uses an external pointer internally is a strong indicator that it cannot be exported to another R process or saved to file or read back again.  You can check for external pointers using (non-public) `future:::assert_no_references()`, e.g.

```
> library(raster)
> r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
> future:::assert_no_references(r)
NULL     ## == no external pointer

> s <- raster(r)
> future:::assert_no_references(s)
NULL     ## == no external pointer

> s <- writeStart(s[[1]], filename='test.grd',  overwrite=TRUE)
> future:::assert_no_references(s)
Error: Detected a non-exportable reference ('externalptr') in one of the globals (<unknown>) used in the future expression
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem. Thanks for making it clear. So for blockwise raster processing no parallelization is possible?  The only possibility would be a blockwise raster processing by looping over the rasterstack. This would be very inefficient in my opinion. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I suggest reaching out to the maintainer of **raster** for recommendations on parallelization using their data structures.